# google firebase auth server database name

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying use this snipet.  What is the name of <DATABASE_NAME>?  where i can find it

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
  .setServiceAccount(new FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json"))
  .setDatabaseUrl("https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/")
  .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

Comment: Not really.  The solution for my case is remove this from the code: setDatabaseUrl("https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/")

Comment: Good to hear . Can you post that as a self-answer, so that others can benefit from it?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the URL in the [database panel](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/hands/data) of the Firebase console for your project:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally following the instruccions of google i found that this portion of snipet code is optional.  I removed.